# Getting null from foreach running on gridview to compare buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This code seems to work fine on my friend's webpage however when I try and compare the button either with the '==' operator or the .Equals function it doesn't enter the if statement.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int orderid = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridViewOrders.Rows)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)gvr.FindControl("ButtDetailedView");
        if (btn == (Button)sender)
            orderid = int.Parse(gvr.Cells[0].Text);
    }
    if (orderid != 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ViewOrderDetails.aspx?OrderId=" + orderid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use ((Button)sender).Name instead of finding a control and 
comparing object references?

Comment: have you bound this event `Button1_Click` to other buttons also?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be that your `Button1_Click` event is bound to <kbd>Button1</kbd> and **not** bound to <kbd>ButtDetailedView</kbd>. Therefore the sender cannot be <kbd>ButtDetailedView</kbd> and your comparison:

```
Button btn = (Button)gvr.FindControl("ButtDetailedView");
if (btn.Equals((Button)sender))
```

returns `false`